# What to do with an expression of the form: $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

We are looking at the following expression:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(x) dx$$

The solution is straightforward for this: $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t) dt$. Do we evaluate the given expression in like manner? Do we treat the $f(x) dx$ as if it were $f(t) dt$?

Comment: Where did you see this ill-defined expression?

Comment: My daughter's homework. I suspected it might be an error.

Comment: With all due respect, if there is no typo in the expression, the homework is really bad.

Comment: Yes. It's an error in the homework. Now that we've confirmed that, the specific exercise is easy.

Answer (score 2):

This expression is badly written. It only makes sense to understand it as
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)dt
$$
where the dummy variable for the definite integral should *not* be the same as any variable in the bounds.

The general method for dealing with such derivative is called the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), which tells you how to find
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}g(x,t)\,dt
$$

Your question is a special case where $g(x,t)=f(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

You should write $\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)dt$. Then use the fundamental theorem of calculus by first rewriting

$$\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)dt = \int_{c}^{v(x)}f(t)dt+\int_{u(x)}^{c}f(t)dt=\int_{c}^{v(x)}f(t)dt-\int_{c}^{u(x)}f(t)dt$$
for any constant $c$. The notation $\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(x)dx$ does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the name of variables !

The $x$ in $v(x)$ is not the same as $dx$ lets call it $dt$

Consider your integral as a primitive

$$I(x)=F(v(x))-F(u(x))$$ with $F$ a primitive of   $f$. From here it is easy to use **chain rule** and conclude for an expression.